# Voting for pure contest questions?

Tags: discussion, voting, contests

So,  I just saw this querstion [If both $a,b>0$, then $a^ab^b \ge a^bb^a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063223/old-oxford-scholarship-question-aabb-ge-abba) ,  and I became confused at the number of upvotes it had.  I perused the policies here on meta, and I see that questions like this are allowable.

However, I thought that upvoting questions was for questions that were considered 'good' by a metric that included context,   the questioner's thoughts on the issue, etc.  It seems to me that simply copy and pasting an interesting past contest question doesn't meet those standards....or am I wrong in my interpretation of the intent of the voting system for questions?

Comment: You’re certainly wrong about how people actually do determine whether to upvote a question, even limiting the field to MSE regulars. As user $147263$ suggests, though, outsiders very probably are the reason for the bizarrely high vote counts on this question and its answers.

Comment: It may be the subject matter making it "Hot" as it is simple enough to understand.  I have never really understood why my highest voted answer was a brief statement on [Fastest way to check if $x^y > y^x$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517555/fastest-way-to-check-if-xy-yx/517567#517567) but then I stopped caring how other people voted.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Your puzzlement is only natural. After a while, you will know for a fact that **anything** can get upvotes on MSE. **Any** question. Even answerable by clicking on the first google link? You bet. **Any** answer. Even dead wrong? Absolutely. Thus my advice would be (1) to take votes (and reputations) with a healthy dose of skepticism and (2) to move on. Good luck. -- [Did](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13748/how-can-this-naive-question-get-upvotes#comment54072_13748)

One popular method for getting a lot of upvotes is:

1. Give the question a non-technical and somewhat vague/intriguing title.
2. Do not use LaTeX in the title.
3. Make sure your question is not too difficult, so that a couple answers will be posted quickly.
4. Yet, it should  not be completely standard, so that the answers get a few quick upvotes.
5. If you did 1-4 right, your question will enter [Hot Network List](http://stackexchange.com/) and will be shown to 6 million people visiting Stack Overflow every day.
6. If they have a minute to kill, they will click on your question, and probably upvote (they have 101 reputation here, so they can upvote but can't downvote).
7. At long last...
8. **Profit!**

As you can see from the revision history, this question followed steps 1-4 successfully. The votes that it got have little to do with any policies or preferences of the users of this site.

Comment: We might argue if this is a healthy practice!

Comment: Make sure the title is vaguely misleading so that it stands out on the Hot Network Question (see: any hot network question from the [gaming stack exchange](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197675/is-marrying-my-own-sister-a-good-idea)). May I suggest the hairy ball theorem?